# How to clear a td content upon deleting/backspacing/clearing text in a textbox

Tags: javascript, php, jquery

I am working in php/JQuery and this is what I have coded so far ...
**username.php**

```
<html>
<head>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="js/jquery-1.7.1.min.js"></script>

    <script type="text/javascript">

        $(document).ready(function(){

            $("#username").change(function(){

                if($('#username').val().length == 0){

                    $('#message').empty();
                }
                else{

                    $("#message").html("<img src='images/loader.gif' /> checking...");

                    var username = $("#username").val();

                    $.post( "check.php", { user: $("#username").val() }, function (data){
                        if(data == 0){

                            $("#message").html("<img src='images/tick.png' /><span style='font-size:13px; color: black'> Username available</span>");                               
                            proceed = true;

                        }
                        else{

                            $("#message").html("<img src='images/err.png' /><span style=font-size:13px; color: red'> Username already taken</span>");                               
                            proceed = false;
                        }
                    });                     
                }       
            });
        });

    </script>

</head>

<body>  
    <form id="user">           
        <table>
            <tr>
                <td>Username</td>
                <td>:</td>
                <td><input type="text" name="username" id="username"/></td>
                <td id="message"></td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td>Password</td>
                <td>:</td>
                <td><input type="text" name="password" id="password" /></td>
            </tr>
        </table>

        <button type="submit" name="submit" >Check</button>
    </form> 
</body>
</html>
```

Now what I want to achieve is:

As I **backspace/delete** the whole text in the textbox with the **ID = "username"** , this should clear the text that appears in the td with the **ID = "message"**    
How can achieve this with javascript.
Any help will be much appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Use [`keyup`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Events/keyup)/[`input`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Events/input) event instead of `change` or Both events together for backward compatibility.

Try this:

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  $("#username").on('input, keyup', function() {
    if ($('#username').val().length == 0) {
      $('#message').empty();
    } else {
      $("#message").html("<img src='images/loader.gif' /> checking...");
      var username = $("#username").val();
      $.post("check.php", {
        user: $("#username").val()
      }, function(data) {
        if (data == 0) {
          $("#message").html("<img src='images/tick.png' /><span style='font-size:13px; color: black'> Username available</span>");
          proceed = true;
        } else {
          $("#message").html("<img src='images/err.png' /><span style=font-size:13px; color: red'> Username already taken</span>");
          proceed = false;
        }
      });
    }
  });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
<form id="user">
  <table>
    <tr>
      <td>Username</td>
      <td>:</td>
      <td>
        <input type="text" name="username" id="username" />
      </td>
      <td id="message"></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>Password</td>
      <td>:</td>
      <td>
        <input type="text" name="password" id="password" />
      </td>
    </tr>
  </table>
  <button type="submit" name="submit">Check</button>
</form>
```